# Open a new activity on button click

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, onclick

I am trying to open activity "one" from "MainActivity" when button "button1" (onClick:one) is clicked.

This is the code in my "MainActivity":

```
    public void one(View view) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, one.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

And this is my AndroidManifeste.xml:

```
        <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tictactoe12players.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
       android:name="com.example.players.one"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_activity1">
      </activity>
```

But the "activity_activity1.xml" isn't opening: when I tried it on the emulator it wrote activity1 and then crashed.

Comment: Have you declared activity one in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

To "create" a new Activity, you must declare it in your AndroidManifest.xml, in your case, it will look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="one"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
</activity>
```

You must put these four lines in the < application> section like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="one"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.Test if you are enter in the function

```
 public void one(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "enter one() function", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    (...)
}
```

2.Try this

```
Activity activity = this;
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, one.class);
activity.startActivity(intent);
activity.finish();
```

Comment: To trace the execution debugging using breakpoint is the best way.Don't waste time with dump codes